# Rails 4.2.3 app not working in production environment but working in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I deployed my rails app on AWS instance which is working fine if I change the environment to development instead of production in the `.conf` file of nginx.

Following is the output of `production.log` content

```
I, [2015-10-01T08:22:36.180713 #3376]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 123.252.135.162 at 2015-10-01 08:22:36 +0000
F, [2015-10-01T08:22:36.201807 #3376] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
```

Following is the content of `production.rb` file

```
# config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
config.serve_static_files = true

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
# config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

# Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
config.assets.compile = true

# Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
# yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
config.assets.digest = true
```

I tried running

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

which generated the assets folder in public directory. But still when I access the url of my app, it shows the page you are looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: is your `routes.rb` file present in production? Might be worth running `rake routes`.

Comment: I did run rake routes. routes.rb file is present and the routes are working fine if I change the environment to development in conf file. So there is no problem related to routes I guess

Comment: what about the rails environment setup in your apache/nginx config, is that set to production? If it is in production you will need to restart the rails app for changes to take effect unlike in development.

Comment: I did change the environment to production in my nginx .conf file. I also restarted the server to apply the changes but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. Actually the app is running fine if I access other resources like

```
myapp.com/users
```

But when I access the `myapp.com` it shows the page doesn't exist which you are looking for. This is because the rails default server serves the rails default page in development environment but when I tried to run the same in production environment, nginx doesn't serve the default page of rails.